# Liferay aui css overriding

Tags: css, liferay, liferay-6, freemarker, alloy-ui

we have created a simple Webcontent template with Liferay 6.2 EE.

The template was built with freemarker.

Now we want to use our own homemade css file to apply our style to the webcontent template.

But liferay's aui.css seems to override some of our css styles.

*What's the best way to integrate our css file within freemarkers webcontent template ?*

*Is it possible to override aui.css ?*

Thanks

Comment: Without a more specific knowledge of your actual DOM/CSS: "Just" be more specific than Liferay's selectors...

Comment: In order to override the styles in **`aui.css`**, there are at least two possible solutions:

 1. [Create a Liferay Theme](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/developing-a-liferay-theme) which [contains the CSS file](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/styling-your-theme-with-css) you want to include with your web content.

Comment: 2. Add CSS in a `<style>` element in your template to override some of the styles in **`aui.css`**. However, be warned that [the HTML spec requires that `<style>` elements be a child of the `<head>` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-style-element), so if you plan on including a `<style>` element inside the `<body>` tag, your HTML will be invalid. I believe that most modern browsers will ignore this and render the page as expected.

Comment: There is [a similar question on the Liferay Forums](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/14801284) which discusses these solutions in more depth.

Comment: Where did you put your custom css and could you please give some examples. It seems pretty trivial to me, since aui.css is easy to override but more info is needed.

Comment: @Michael I put my custom css straight away in my template. But i only created a <style></style> tag and placed my css inside this tag.

Comment: @stiemannkj1 I'll go through the proposals made in the Liferay Forum. Thanks for the link.

Comment: But in general my approch is to put my custom css inside my webcontent template with the <style> tag.

Comment: You can use the !important for the Css or Change the loading order of the css

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your styles within aui class:

```
.aui {
//your styles goes here
}
```